# Progressbar TaskStatus does listen to all async runs

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

I made a small example for you guyes to see what i mean.

By Running it you will see that on clicking into the Yellow area the progress bar is shown... But i only want it to be shown if the Green area is clicked.

Am i doing sth wrong or is this actually an expected behavior?

```
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox
import tornadofx.*

class RunAsyncExample : View() {
    override val root = VBox()
    private val runAsyncOne: RunAsyncOne by inject()
    private val runAsyncTwo: RunAsyncTwo by inject()

    init {
        with(root) {
            minWidth = 400.0
            minHeight = 300.0
            add(runAsyncOne)
            add(runAsyncTwo)
        }
    }
}

class RunAsyncOne : View() {
    override val root = AnchorPane()

    init {
        with(root) {
            var checker = false
            minWidth = 400.0
            minHeight = 150.0
            style {
                backgroundColor += c("YELLOW")
            }
            setOnMouseClicked {
                checker = !checker
                runAsync {
                    while (checker) {
                        Thread.sleep(100)
                        println("AsyncOne")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class RunAsyncTwo : View() {
    override val root = VBox()
    private val status: TaskStatus by inject()

    init {
        with(root) {
            minWidth = 400.0
            minHeight = 150.0
            setOnMouseClicked {
                runAsync {
                    var b = 0.0
                    while (b < 100.0) {
                        b+=1
                        updateProgress(b, 100.0)
                        updateMessage("$b / 100.0")
                        Thread.sleep(100)
                        println("AsyncTwo")
                    }
                }
            }
            stackpane {
            visibleWhen { status.running }
                progressbar(status.progress) {
                    progress = 0.0
                    minWidth = 400.0
                }
                label(status.message)
            }
            style {
                backgroundColor += c("GREEN")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When i click into the green area:
[image]
When i click into the yellow area while the AsyncTwo is running,
the progress bar is changing but i dont want that...
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you inject a `TaskStatus` object into your View, you will get a "global" `TaskStatus` object that by default will report status of any async calls. What you want is to create a local `TaskStatus` object for the `RunAsyncTwo` View and pass that to the `runAsync` call.

If you don't pass a `TaskStatus` object to `runAsync`, the default for your scope will be used, hence the behavior you're seeing. Here is an example with a local `TaskStatus` object for the second view. Please also note that I'm using a more sensible syntax for defining the root node, you should absolutely pick this pattern up :)

```
class RunAsyncTwo : View() {
    private val status = TaskStatus()

    override val root = vbox {
        minWidth = 400.0
        minHeight = 150.0
        setOnMouseClicked {
            runAsync(status) {
                var b = 0.0
                while (b < 100.0) {
                    b += 1
                    updateProgress(b, 100.0)
                    updateMessage("$b / 100.0")
                    Thread.sleep(100)
                    println("AsyncTwo")
                }
            }
        }
        stackpane {
            visibleWhen(status.running)
            progressbar(status.progress) {
                progress = 0.0
                minWidth = 400.0
            }
            label(status.message)
        }
        style {
            backgroundColor += c("GREEN")
        }
    }
}
```